# Bootstrap flex row image same height as div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using the latest Bootstrap 5.0 beta version and I have the following html snippet:

```
    <div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <img src="img/funny.png" alt="">
            <div class="ms-4">
                This is just
                <br>a simple test
                <br>with some line breaks
                <br>just to get some height
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So a flexbox row with an image left of a div with text context. Now I want to make the image the same height as the div. How can I do this in a responsive way? Right now I get something like this

[image]

Comment: Its not possible, without giving max-height to an image the probable solution for this issue is, Either you can align content to centre of image or if content is bigger than image then you can align image to centre of image.
```display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center```

Comment: Could please show a complete sample?

Comment: @fraz gsell I have made minor changes in your code and have upload my answer below. Please have a look.
Example: https://www.codeply.com/p/p7mfcnWVZ7

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with flex Container. Where is the Problem to give the img max-height width:auto?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some minor modification in your code, now you can place an image of any size the corresponding text will remain center.
Example: [here](https://www.codeply.com/p/p7mfcnWVZ7)

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
<div class="align-self-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/09f.png/fff%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/#How_To_Use_Our_Placeholders" alt="">
</div>
<div class="ml-4 align-self-center">
    This is just a simple test with some line breaks just to get some height
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, but I was looking for an approach where the image height automatically fits the text height in the other div